# Node.js how to use this and call functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

In IntelliJi create the following node.js application:

The application will include two files. The students.js file and the app.js file.

In the students.js file, the following modules will exist:

changeStudentInfo - which when called will store the student name, student number, student address, student city, student state, and student zipcode into variables that can be accessed by another function. The information is passed into the function from the app.js program. HINT: Watch the "this pointer" video along with the "module' video.

displayStudentInfo - which will display the contents of the variables that were set in the changeStudentInfo function.

The app.js file will:

Call the displayStudentInfo function to display the DEFAULT values for each of the variables.

Call the changeStudentInfo function to change the variable information to YOUR information. (You can use a fake address).

Call the displayStudentInfo function to display the changed values.

HERE IS WHAT I HAVE SO FAR FOR THE student file

```
var info = {
    name: "Default",
    major: "Major",
    sum: function(){
        console.log(this.name);
        console.log(this.major);
    }

};




function changeStudentInfo() {
    this.name = "Kita";
   this.address = "CandyLane";

}
function displayStudentInfo(){
    info.sum();
  }

module.exports.studentinfo = displayStudentInfo;
module.exports.studentupdate = changeStudentInfo;
```

HERE IS WHAT I HAVE IN THE APP FILE

```
var student = require('./student');

student.studentinfo();

student.studentupdate();
```

Comment: I understand how to get it to print something by calling the function. I am stuck on the change part. How do I get it to change the data and then reprint the same function with the new data?

Answer (score 1):

Change into this to modify student info -

```
function changeStudentInfo(name, address) {
  info.name = name;
  info.address = address;
}
```

Then call this function from app file like this -

```
student.studentupdate('Kita', 'CandyLane');
```

In app file do this -

```
var student = require('./student');
student.studentinfo();
student.studentupdate('Kita', 'CandyLane');
student.studentinfo();
```

Comment: first it has to display the defaults in info, then it has to call change to update, then it has to display new values

Comment: thank you! I got it to work... your example set me on the right path. I was able to set all the new variables in the student file and then call it from app. much appreciated!